# How to perform a transaction on a chaincode through java or node sdk which requires two organisation admins signature?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Suppose I installed a chain code on a channel with signature policy 2 of [org1. Admin, org2.Admin]. Now I want to invoke the transaction from Org1 I will have my organization admin keys but still, I will not be able to make the transaction as I do not have the key of the admin of organization 2 to perform the signature. so how to satisfy such policy?

Further explanation: In my chain code policy, I defined that every transaction for that chain code need to be signed by org1.admin and org2.admin and suppose I am doing the transaction through org1 I peers I have credential of my admin(org1.admin) but I do not have credentials of the admin of org2, so how do I get sufficient signatures? Is such use case possible(multi-signature use cases )

Comment: What is it exactly are you trying to achieve? If the transaction is sent to the peers of org2 it will automatically be signed by org2 [provided the chaincode is installed on org2 peers]. Not sure, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: in my chain code policy, I defined that every transaction for that chain code need to be signed by org1.admin and org2.admin and suppose I am doing the transaction through org1 I peers I have credential of my admin(org1.admin) but I do not have credentials of the admin of org2, so how do I get sufficient signatures? Is such use case possible(multi-signature use cases )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you're looking for.

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/endorsement-policies.html

You use endorsement policies to have multi signature on transactions by instantiating it with certain policies. In this case, signature policy required by two members.

Comment: Above link is about configuring the endorsement policies in chain code and my question is how to acquire signatures of these two members as they are the participant of two different organization.

Comment: That's done automatically through the endorsement policy set on the chaincode when you instantiate it with the policy. This section "...AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member')" is supposed to define which signatures are necessary when you invoke methods from the chaincode for ledger manipulation. Isn't that what you want, for an org to sign a tx?

Comment: How will I get the signature from all these organizations as they are running on separate nodes?

Comment: It's supposed to be done automatically with the Gossip protocol. Once the network is setup, peers have the network mapped out (anchor peers, MSPs, ordereres, etc..). They have the address and port of where each org is accessible and who the admins are. If you want to restrict and be notified of what the org is signing, you can use chaincode events.